# Ruby on Rails - Failed to create new user: Validation failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, postman

On creating a new user using postman, I'm getting the following error:

> Failed to create new user: Validation failed: First name can't be blank, Email can't be blank, Email is invalid; Params: {:email=>nil, :first_name=>nil, :last_name=>nil, :plan=>"Basic", :role=>"requester_readonly", :phone_number=>nil, :ip=>nil, :company_name=>nil, :product_id=>2, :user_reference_id=>nil, :handle=>nil}

Error on postman:

```
{
    "error": [
        "First name can't be blank",
        "Email can't be blank",
        "Email is invalid"
    ],
    "status": 400
}
```

I am passing the following values to params in postman:

```
{
    "email": "customer@yahoo.com",
    "firstName": "Demo",
    "lastName": "Customer",
    "password": "Password_0",
    "phoneNumber": "0123456789",
    "ip": "10.10.2.125",
    "company": "xyz"
}
```

This is the function for user registration:

```
def register
        product_id = $product_id
        if params[:plan]
        @plan = AppCommon::Plan.where(name: params[:plan], product_id: product_id).first
      end
      @plan = @plan || AppCommon::Plan.find_default(product_id)

          form_params = {email: params[:email], first_name: params[:firstName], last_name: params[:lastName], password: params[:password], plan: @plan.name, role: 'requester_readonly', phone_number: params[:phoneNumber], ip: params[:ip], company_name: params[:company], product_id: product_id, user_reference_id: params[:referenceId]}
          service = Web::UserCreater.new(form_params)
        result = service.perform
        @user = service.user
        if result.success?
          render json: {status: 200, authentication_token: @user.authentication_token}
        else
          error_response(@user.errors.full_messages.to_a)
        end
      end
```

Comment: Can you post the actual params from the log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably the ruby on rails controllers are wrapping the params under a name https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html

you can either turn it off by setting `wrap_parameters false` on the top of your controller **but I do not advise on this!**

you could probably print/log the entire params to see how they look like and probably permit them

pull `form_params` into its own method require the param wrapper then permit what you need

```rb
def form_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name, :password, :phone_number, :ip, :company_name, :user_reference_id)
end
```

then in your method get these params then merge the defaults:

```rb
user_creater_attributes = form_params.merge(product_id: product_id, plan: @plan.name, role: 'requester_readonly')
```